# Relationship between $||A^{-1}-B||$ and $||B^{-1}-A||$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

If I have a bound such that $ C \leq ||A^{-1}-B|| \leq D$, does it imply anything about on the $||B^{-1}-A||$, where A, B are square invertible, positive definite matrices with elements in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$B^{-1} - A = A(A^{-1} B^{-1} - I) = A(A^{-1} - B)B^{-1}$$

So if $\| \cdot \|$ is a submultiplicative norm, you get the following estimate:
$$\|B^{-1} - A\| \le \|A\| \|A^{-1} - B\| \|B^{-1}\| \le \|A\| \|B^{-1}\| D.$$

Similarly, the inequality
$\|A^{-1} - B\| \le \|B\|\|B^{-1} - A\| \|A^{-1}\|$ holds, which implies

$$\|B^{-1} - A\| \ge C \|B\|^{-1} \|A^{-1}\|^{-1}.$$

These estimates should be tight, just look at the case of $1 \times 1$-matrices.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$ B^{-1}-A=B^{-1}(A^{-1}-B)A$$